# Styled Components: How to target direct children?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I saw in the docs that the & selector was used for nested targeting. But the following does not work. What is the correct syntax to use here?

```
const InlineContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;

  & > * {
    margin-right: "40px";
  }
`;
```

Comment: `margin-right: 40px;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As CSS value, the string `"40px"` is invalid where the value `40px` does.

```
const FlexBox = styled.div`
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid palevioletred;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  > * {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  > div {
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
`;
```

[image: Edit Q-58690167-DirectChildExample]

Comment: Thank you, this also worked. I guess in this case the & was unneeded

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
const InlineContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;

  > * {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
`;
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot also to remove the unwanted " " around the value